# Unable to remotely connect to SSIS catalog

Tags: ssms, ssis

I have an SSIS installation on which I can not connect through our Citrix hosted Sql Server Management studio.

I can connect to it when running SSMS locally.
But if I try to connect remotely, with the Citrix hosted SSMS, I receive the following error:

> Cannot connect to dummyname.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer
>   "dummyname" failed with the following error: "Access is denied."
>
> By default, only administrators have access to the Integration
>   Services service. On Windows Vista and later, the process must be
>   running with administrative privileges in order to connect to the
>   Integration Services service. See the help topic for information on
>   how to configure access to the service.
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220763
>
> ---
>
> Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer
>   "dummyname" failed with the following error: "Access is denied."
>
> By default, only administrators have access to the Integration
>   Services service. On Windows Vista and later, the process must be
>   running with administrative privileges in order to connect to the
>   Integration Services service. See the help topic for information on
>   how to configure access to the service.

I have set the following configurations:

- The user connecting to the SSIS has sysadmin
- The user connecting to the SSIS has db_ssisadmin
- The user connecting to the SSIS has db_owner on the msdb database
- At the component services, SSIS properties I set the Security for Launch and activiation permissions, access permissions, configuration permissions
- At the component services, SSIS properties I set the location as `Run application on this computer`
- I added the user to the local group Distributed COM Users
- I added the user as a local administrator
- I gave the service user permissions for `Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos Only)`

What have I missed, what else could be causing this error.
Perhaps something unique to citrix?